# Compare number with 3 numbers

Tags: javascript

Compare the displayed numbers with three numbers

I receive a number(1-100) and I want to display a popup when it does not match any of the the numbers of (80,90,100)

```
 if (input != 80) {      

   if (input != 90 ) {       

     if (input != 100) {   log.info('Display' +input)   

      }     
    } 
  }
```

Comment: which language are u using , U have mentioned both the tag Java and JavaScript, be specific to get a better and specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `includes` method of Array to simplify this:

```
if (![80, 90, 100].includes(input)) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I used .contains because includes do not work in my IDE :)

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you can create an input var and store value.

then put if the condition

> like this

var input=65;

```
if(input !=80){
    if(input != 90){
        if(input !=100){
            console.log("display:"+input);
        }
    }
}
```

its work

```js
var input=65;
if(input !=80){
    if(input != 90){
        if(input !=100){
            console.log("display:"+input);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with logical || operator

```
if (input != 80 || input != 90 || input != 100) {     
  ...
}
```

Comment: You probably mean to use '&&'

Answer (score 1):

You can nicely use arrays and `indexOf()`:

```
if ([80, 90, 100].indexOf(input) < 0) {
    //Do something...
}
```